# Parameterized queries broken with plv8

Tags: postgresql, plv8

I've been trying to get plv8 working on PostgreSQL 10 (completely clean install, never used it before).  I've created a function like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FindActivitiesJS(_id integer)
  RETURNS Text AS
  $BODY$
  var queryResult = plv8.execute('SELECT * FROM activities WHERE activityid = $1', [_id]);
  return JSON.stringify(queryResult);
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plv8 VOLATILE;
```

When I run:

```
select * from findactivitiesjs(3)
```

I get:

> ERROR:  Error: there is no parameter $0 DETAIL:  findactivitiesjs()
>   LINE 2:   var queryResult = plv8.execute('SELECT * FROM activities
>   WHERE activityid =  SQL state: XX000

I've also tried changing the SQL query to `SELECT * FROM activities WHERE activityid = $0` but same results.  It's something about the parameter on the query, since a SELECT statement with no WHERE clause works fine.

What am  doing wrong?

Comment: not related, but why not `SELECT to_json(activities) FROM activities WHERE activityid = $1` and sql function?..

Comment: @VaoTsun - Yup sounds better, but I'd like to fix my error first.

Comment: alas - I'm on osx at home - don't think I ill manage to install plv8 :)

Comment: You must have made a mistake building PL/v8. Your function works for me with the PL/v8 binaries from PGDG on Linux and PostgreSQL v10.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - Yup, looks like PL/v8 is just totally broken on Windows.  I just tried the Linux version and it works great.  Go figure.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - BTW, I got the binaries from [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/379-PLV8-binaries-for-PostgreSQL-10-windows-both-32-bit-and-64-bit.html) so maybe if I built them myself it would work..

Comment: You never said it was Windows... you might try asking the project at https://github.com/plv8/plv8/issues

Comment: Yea I didn't think the OS mattered.  I figured it was something wrong with my syntax.